In c++ cv::calibrateCamera doesn´t converge to the right solution but in python yes
I’m working on calibrating a camera with C++, but it’s not working. The resulting matrix K has no relation to the camera’s actual values, and with an RMSE (root mean square error) of approximately 200.0. However, using the same images in Python, it works and with an RMSE of 0.05
I’m work on windows.
c++:
opencv 4.8.0#15 from vcpkg
python:
opencv-python 4.8.0.72
Code c++:
//parametros y criterios del patron de calibracion
const int rows=11;
const int columns=8;
const cv::Size tableSize(rows, columns);
const float world_scaling=15.0;
const cv::Size conv_size(11,11);
const cv::TermCriteria criteria(cv::TermCriteria::EPS | cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 100, 1.0E-5);

for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
        objp[i * columns + j] = cv::Point3f(j * world_scaling, i * world_scaling, 0.0);
    }
}
auto images = readImg("../data/cam1");
const int width = images[0].cols;
const int height = images[0].rows;
objPoints1.clear();
imgPoints1.clear();
for (size_t i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)
{
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners1;
    bool found_1 = cv::findChessboardCorners(images[i], tableSize, corners1,cv::CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH);
    if (found_1) {
        cv::cornerSubPix(images[i], corners1, conv_size, cv::Size(-1, -1), criteria);
        objPoints1.push_back(objp);
        imgPoints1.push_back(corners1);
    }
}

//Calibrar cada cámara individualmente 
//Camara 1
cv::Mat cameraMatrix1;
cv::Mat distCoeffs1;
std::vector<cv::Mat> rvecs1, tvecs1;
const cv::Size size(width, height);

double ret = cv::calibrateCamera(objPoints1, imgPoints1, size, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, rvecs1, tvecs1);

python:
rows=11
columns=8
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.00001)
objp = np.zeros((self.rows*self.columns,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:self.rows,0:self.columns].T.reshape(-1,2)
objp = self.world_scaling* objp
    
# #Pixel coordinates of checkerboards
imgpoints_l = [] # 2d points in image plane.
objpoints_l = [] # 3d point in real world space

# Images are grayscales
for img_l in zip(list_images):
    found_l, corners_l = cv.findChessboardCorners(img_l, (self.rows, self.columns),flags=cv.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH)
    if found_l:
       corners_l = cv.cornerSubPix(img_l, corners_l, self.conv_size, (-1, -1), self.criteria)
       objpoints_l.append(objp)
       imgpoints_l.append(corners_l)
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints_l, imgpoints_l,(width,height),None,None)

Could someone help me please? I don’t know what I’m doing bad.
know that in Python it works and in C++ it doesn't for different tests that I have done such as stereo calibration between cameras where the translation matrix is incorrect.
I changed the computer, reinstalled all the packages, rebuilt everything... but nothing
I want to know where the error is, whether it is due to the library I am using or due to malpractice, syntax or anything else that is missing or over.
I'm not new to the subject, I've done it before, but it's the first time it's happened to me on different computers.

Try to compare the intermediate steps' results in python and c++. Very likely, the python version uses a c++ build in the background, so also likely, you have differences in the input or the parameters.

Yes yes, I have compared. The result outing from findChessboardCorners is a little different, with a difference of +/- 0.5 pixels between points.
Yes it's curious, you are right, python runs c++ in background.

I'v been thinking about overflow but cornersubpix doesn't accept double, only float....

you could check the release notes of your exact opencv version differences. A +0.5 fix might be there.

I think... 2nd argument of cv::findChessboardCorners should be (columns, rows).

if the original C++ code worked with your board, ignore this comment. the shape of the board (second argument) specifies the number of saddle points, i.e. interior corners. that is one less than the number of squares along each dimension.

@fana the order of the columns and rows doesn't matter. This merely sets the dimensions of the board and the number of points, rows*columns. Since the board must be rotated, the sequence loses its relevance.

@ChristophRackwitz Yes, actually, my board have a shape of 12x9. Detections work perfectly but cv::calibrateCamera isn't working right

I think that opencv from vcpckg is the problem. I have to try to build the opencv project from GitHub and use it instead vcpkg
